# How do we call a function within the html file of vuejs defined in the javascript file of vuejs without creating a button in the html file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I pretty new to vuejs and am building a vuejs project. One of the tasks I am stuck at is, that I want to call a function written in the javascript part of vuejs from the html part of vuejs without creating any buttons or textboxes. I want to call this function as soon as my app starts. How do I achieve this? When I use mounted (vue lifecycle hook), the page it redirects to keeps refreshing. would appreciate some leads on this.

For example, I have a code:

```
<template>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<!--I WANT TO CALL THE auth0login function here. How do I do that without creating a button/text field,etc -->
</template>

<script>

export default {

  data: () => ({
    return : {
      clientID: process.env.example
    }
  }),

  methods:{
    auth0login(){
      console.log('logging in via Auth0!');
      Store.dispatch('login');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to call the auth0login function defined in the script part in the html part above in order to execute the functionalities of the auth0login function. I want to do this without creating any buttons in the html file and simply just execute the auth0login function when the app launches. 
How do I do this?

Comment: The `mounted()` hook is totally appropriate, but what does the function you want to call exactly. Could you provide a basic example of what you tried already?

Comment: ```mounted: function() {
    console.log('logging in via Auth0!');
    this.auth0login()
    }
}
```

The function that I am calling is the auth0login function. This function further calls another function which is used for authenticating the login details using auth0. Basically, it will redirect the user to the auth0 login page, take the credentials of the user, authenticate it and then redirect it to the dashboard if the username and password is correct. The issue occurs when after logging in successfully. The dashboard keeps refreshing everytime.

Comment: The auth0 authentication code works fine when I add a button in the html file and then call the auth0login function. But when I remove that part and I just try to call the auth0login function using mounted, it keeps refreshing the redirected page after logging in sucessfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call auth0login() only when you're not already logged I guess.

Comment: auth0login() does all the internal checking if the user is logged in or not.
Is there a way to make a call to a function from the html file without creating a button/text field etc)?

Comment: Nope. Sorry to insist but your "internal checking" must include some redirection even when the user is logged-in, that's the only explanation.

Comment: Thank you. checking if logged in or not did help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is after user already logged in, they go back to the initial page, and the function in **mounted()** hook run again. Thats why they keep get redirect to login page. This not happen when you insert the button, because the button require user to click at it.

To fix this, you need to define a `vuex state` to store whether user has logged in or not, and in **mounted()** hook, just called it when they not login yet.

So. Instead of

```
mounted: function() { console.log('logging in via Auth0!'); this.auth0login() } }
```

Add a check login state

```
mounted() {
 if(!this.$store.state.userLoggin) // here i define userLoggin and vuex state, you should update it to true whenever user successfully login
   { console.log('logging in via Auth0!'); this.auth0login() //only call it when user not loggin
    }
}
```

And remember to update your `vuex state.userLoggin` when user successfully login in the `auth0login()` function

Comment: Thank you. The logic you suggested works for the above-mentioned test case. But, if I keep that if statement and I close the website without logging out, and again open the website, then it does not direct me to the dashboard (instead I get a blank page). This happens coz userLoggin is True as we had logged in a while ago (the access token is still a valid one) and hence, it does not call the auth0login() which has all the entire functionalities of loading the pages if already authorized or not.

Comment: I can solve this issue by  adding an else statement for redirecting to the dashboard page is already logged in but then it will keep loading that page coz of the mounted cycle. Is there a way to break out of the mounted cycle after a specific operation is done?

Comment: Thats strange cause usually vuex is cleared when browser is closed, did you store vuex state userLogin in localStorage ?

Comment: Yes, the session gets stored in the localStorage. 
Is there a way to break out of the mounted hook life cycle once the auth0login() is called? That way instead of keeping the "if" check for the user is already logged in or not, we can simply break out of the mounted life cycle when auth0login() is called only once.